# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\pyCHram\\<input>'

Tags: python, pycharm, oserror

I use ‘ProcessPoolExecutor’ to handle some data on PyCharm,but i get this error："OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\pyCHram\'"。
But I don't know why, I dont write any code about the file path.
'D:\pyCHram\' is the folder that i save python file.  Thank you very much for answering my questions.
The part of the code is below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_result = []
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
    for i in range(3):
        future = pool.submit(search,poolArgsList[i],data_1)
      ###poolArgsList[i] and data_1   both areparameter.
        data_result.append(future)
    endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    print((endTime-startTime).seconds)
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

That does look like an error I bit my teeth out once.
In my case, it did not happen, once executed from terminal instead of PyCharm's console.
A workaround was to `set __file__ = 'workaround.py'` (an empty file in the directory of your project).

Got the workaround from the comments of the open issue at jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36151/Can-t-create-Pool-in-multiprocessing-in-Python-Console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).